# Official dictionary of the U.S. judiciary system?

Tags: statutes, interpretation

Someone recently mentioned the "plain meaning" rule in one of my questions about statutory interpretation. Is there an official dictionary - like Merriam-Webster - that judges are supposed to rely on? Or do we assume that any of the leading publishers of dictionaries have essentially identical definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a single "standard" dictionary that judges use. Presumably any well regarded and common one will do as long as it can be cited. You can see from Justice Alito's opinion in [Intel Investment Policy Comm vs Sulyma](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/19pdf/18-1116_h3cj.pdf) that he references several dictionaries.

> Although ERISA does not define the phrase “actual knowledge,” its
>   meaning is plain.  Dictionaries are hardly necessary to confirm the
>   point, but they do.  When Congress passed ERISA, the word “actual”
>   meant what it means to-day:  “existing  in  fact  or  reality.”  Webster’s  Seventh  New  Collegiate Dictionary 10 (1967); accord,
>   Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate  Dictionary  13  (11th  ed.  2005) 
>   (same);  see  also American  Heritage  Dictionary  14  (1973)  (“In 
>   existence;real; factual”); id., at 18 (5th ed. 2011) (“Existing in
>   reality and not potential, possible, simulated, or false”).  So did
>   the word “knowledge,” which meant and still means “the fact or
>   condition of being aware of something.”  Webster’s Seventh New 
>   Collegiate  Dictionary  469  (1967);  accord,  Merriam-Webster’s
>   Collegiate Dictionary 691 (2005) (same); see also American  Heritage 
>   Dictionary  725  (1973)  (“Familiarity,  awareness, or understanding
>   gained through experience or study”); id.,  at  973  (2011)  (same).
>   Thus,  to  have  “actual  knowledge”  of  a  piece  of  information, 
>   one  must  in  fact  be  aware of it. Legal  dictionaries  give 
>   “actual  knowledge”  the  same  meaning:  “[r]eal  knowledge  as 
>   distinguished  from  presumed  knowledge  or  knowledge  imputed  to 
>   one.”    Ballentine’s Law Dictionary 24 (3d ed. 1969); accord,
>   Black’s Law Dictionary    1043    (11th    ed.    2019) (defining  “actual    knowledge”  as  “[d]irect  and  clear  knowledge,  as 
>   distinguished from constructive knowledge”).

Comment: US courts prefer North American dictionaries over UK or Australian but that’s because there are regional differences in English. If a US court was ruling on a contract under English law no doubt they would use the Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries.

Comment: @DaleM Ha, yes that would be the case.

Comment: Correct. Dictionaries are basically evidence which courts may take judicial notice of, rather than authoritative statements of law, a dictionary is the weakest possible authority for a point, compared, for example, to alternatives like legislative or regulatory definitions, case law, legislative history, legal treatises and law review articles, use in similar statutes, overall context within a statute, and testimony at trial concerning the meaning of a word. Black's law dictionary takes almost all of its definitions from case law.